# "On delete cascade" with three tables. Error cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this table structure ( three tables: image, image_room, room)

```
image
image_id(PK)  |  image_name

image_room
image_id(PK)  |  room_id (PK)

room
room_id(PK)   |  room_name
```

All image id and room id are found in image_room.

When I delete an image from the image table, I want to delete rows with the same id in the image_room. This works fine with this foreign key in image_room

```
columns   | reference Table  | Foreign Columns | On Delete
image_id  | image            | image_id        | CASCADE
```

When I delete a room I want to delete rows with matching room id in image_room AND and all rows in image table matching the id I am deleting from image_room.

I have this foreign key in image_room that erases rooms from image_room

```
columns   | reference Table  | Foreign Columns | On Delete
room_id   | room             | room_id         | CASCADE
```

How do I delete rows from the image table with matching image_id in image_room when I delete a room? Right now Iam guessing that I delete rows in image_room table before image table.

I have tested with this foreign key in image table

```
columns   | reference Table  | Foreign Columns | On Delete
image_id  | image_room       | image_id        | CASCADE
```

And get the error "cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails".

Can I solve this with just On delete cascade? Otherwise, I use PHP as the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

> When I delete a room I want to delete rows with matching room id in image_room AND and all rows in image table matching the id I am deleting from image_room.
>   
> [snip]
>   Can I solve this with just On delete cascade?

No, you can't. In the case of the "image" table, deletes cascade *from* "image" *to* "image_room". (Delete a row from "image", and the dbms deletes all rows in "image_room" that reference that row.) It's impossible to cascade deletes in the other direction.

You'll have to change your design, or use procedural code, either by writing a trigger in MySQL, or by writing application code in PHP.

If image names are unique, you could store the image name in "image_room" instead of storing the image id number. Having done that, and after making sure you've updated that data correctly, you can drop the table "image", and let the single foreign key to "room" do all the clean up.